# Can I, being under 21, hire a car in California?

Tags: usa, car-rentals, california

I'll stay in the US next year for about three months. As I know I can't do much without a car I'd like to hire one. But most rentals are for people over 21 only and I'll only be 19 by then.

Is there another possibility to be mobile around San Francisco Bay Area (hopefully including Santa Cruz Beach)?

Comment: Each company sets its own policies regarding whom they will rent to; there is no statewide minimum set by the law, but you will have a hard time finding any major agency willing to rent to someone under 21. One alternative to look into is joining a car sharing service like [ZipCar](http://www.zipcar.com/).

Comment: It will be tough to find that, and if you do it'll be incredibly expensive. However, SF is a great city to get around, and when you can't walk or take public transit, you can always fall back on Uber.

Comment: @pnuts That's why I said "look into." Car2Go takes anyone over 18, for instance.

Comment: I'd recommend public transportation in the Bay Area.  It can get you almost anywhere and is one of the best systems in the U.S. IMO

Comment: For public transit to Santa Cruz specifically, see [Santa Cruz Metro's Route 17 Bus](http://www.scmtd.com/en/routes).  It runs between Santa Cruz and San Jose, where there are many transit connections (Caltrain from San Francisco and the Peninsula, Capitol Corridor or ACE from the East Bay, as well as local bus and light rail).  The fare is only $5 each way, and the Santa Cruz Metro Center stop is just a few blocks from the beach.

Answer (score 1):

If your age prevents you from dealing with the major rental agencies, you can arrange a private rental through craigslist...

http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/aos?query=rent

This link accesses people offering to rent cars in the entire Bay Area (including suburbs like Pittsburg and Antioch).

Or alternatively, you can compose and run your own advert stating your age and other requirements.  I have used this strategy to rent a car one-way from SF to LA, but I did not have an age problem, I was simply looking for a great deal.  Within about 1 hour of posting my advert I had enough replies to proceed with comfort.

**All craigslist caveats apply.**

Also, some private individuals wishing to rent their cars will make an entry on Relay Rides https://relayrides.com/